# AngularJS + RequireJS + Bower + Karma + Yeoman + Node

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, yeoman, karma-runner, bower

I'm building a app for learning, and I have these major components.
My first question is if these parts are a good foundation for an angularJS app.
I've read in some cases that RequireJS is not a good idea, but not sure why.

My goal is to have a dev environment set up where I have unit and e2e tests, and I want to have this in place before I start coding.

I'm having trouble getting these pieces to work together, and as I push through the issues I thought I'd ask what the latest best practice is to build a non trivial angularJS app.

Comment: Your question should be more specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  What particular issue are you having with these tools.  At the moment, this question is very broad.

Comment: I think the question is fairly specific, are these tools/frameworks/technologies are good foundation for an angularJS app. For instance, maybe a response is like 'don't use Bower because it doesn't work anymore, use xyz instead'. For now, i just want to know if these things form a good foundation, when used together for their intended purposes for an angularJS app.

Comment: Yes, but at present, the responses must be opinion-based.  There is no definitive answer.  IMHO, this is not a good fit for a Q&A format. All of these tools have positives and negatives based on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thx for the comments, I know they'll be opinions, but i thought the opinions would be good for where i currently am in deciding what to learn all at once. Sort of wondering if the angular community was settling on a particular foundation or not

Comment: Not to be heretical (and not in the least trying to be a wise guy), but I find some of SO's most useful answers to be officially deemed "not a good fit for a Q&A format". I understand why they are marked that way. But I must admit that, when in see a question so marked, I pay extra attention, as it usually means enough people have found it useful to bring it to the attention of the People Who Know Such Things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a project that uses AngularJS + RequireJS + Bower + Karma in Github that you can take a look:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/

For me, RequireJS has worked very nicely with AngularJS and together it helped tremendously in both application load time and code organisation.  I do not use Yeoman yet but Grunt and Bower serve as key foundation for dependency sourcing and building of final project.  Karma is a must for unit testing.  You should be able see all these components working together in angularAMD Github project.

Comment: I'll look at it immediately, it uses RequireJS?

Comment: @bmw0128 the whole point of the project is to make RequireJS easier to use with AngularJS :-)

Comment: @bmw0128 do open issue on Github for any comments or enhancements.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague, and answers will be mostly opinions.  Anyway, here's mine…
You definitely need node to run all the modern javascript web development tools.  (grunt, yeoman, karma, mocha, jshint, uglify, coffee, etc, etc.)  Bower is nice to have for updating your client packages.  RequireJS is useful for module loading, but not necessary.  It should work with AngularJS, but keep in mind that the angular "modules" are completely different from RequireJS "modules".  If I were you, I'd work through the Angular tutorial to get a good understanding.  Then start your project with yeoman: `yo angular`.